# LOOKUP in Google spreadsheet oddly applied to row

Tags: google-sheets, lookup

I can't make lookup working properly when used in rows. Where am I wrong ?

See my attempt in the following image[image: the following image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `LOOKUP`? It's very limited in its capability.

To answer your question; it's not working because the `LOOKUP` requires that the search range is in ascending order, i.e. A - Z in your lookup range you go from a - z - e and this is why it's not working.

You should use the `HLOOKUP` instead, try this formula instead: `=HLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$C$3,2,0)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=HLOOKUP(D3,$A$2:$C$3,2,0)
```

Comment: thanks for you answer as well. I just accepted @James ones because of the explanation. But upvote still !